# Trying to set image in main activity from drawable folder of my android project but it is giving me an error

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable

I am trying to use the image to display it in a list view, i copied an image file [(folder.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4jNJ.png) and called it in the main activity. somehow, the called image code is glowing red and giving me an error.

here is my code where image is called.

```
for (File f : files){
            FileModel fm = new FileModel();
            if(f.isFile()){
                fm.setImage(R.drawable.file);
                fm.setName(f.getName());
            }else{
                fm.setImage(R.drawable.folder );//this line is giving me an error.
                 fm.setName(f.getName());
            }
```

Comment: What does say the error?

Comment: Can you post logcat ,is folder is name of image

Comment: you sure name is without space before or after?

Comment: compiler is giving me an error(red glowing text on "folder") i've not tried to run the code yet.(it is unable to resolve the text "folder")

Comment: thanku @JaydeepPatel the error is solved. it had a space before the extension name. (silly mistake)

Comment: always wc happy to help :-)